# is it possible to perform action through console every 5 seconds even when the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to call a function every 5 seconds in a page through console even if the page keeps refreshing?

I tried using `setTimeout`, but it calls the function only once and the page reloads after that and the `setTimeout` is no longer running

I want to trigger a button click every 5 seconds

```
document.getElementsByClassName("postmessage")[0].click()
```

which refreshes the page

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried `setInterval` ??

Comment: no haven't tried it yet. will it be working even when page is refreshed?

Comment: On some browsers you can use [Web Workers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp). In addition you can use frames, so the javascript frame remains static (unaffected by the refresh)... but best of all **don't use the refresh scheme** it's a horrible UX and it waists bandwidth and server resources. There are better ways to do whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: @Myst thanks for the tip. won't the webworkers stop when the page is refreshed?

Comment: @vignesh , the whole point of Web Workers is to allow for scripts to run continuously through page navigations (and probably through a refresh as well). This allows, for example, to have Websocket connections persist across page navigations and even to be shared across multiple tabs, instead of reconnecting the Websocket for every tab / page navigation.

Comment: P.S. **however**, a `refresh` event is often considered to indicate an *issue* (bug) with the page. Browsers might clear out the cache and any page resources during a refresh. If you need polling, consider [AJAJ](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) or [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @Myst, you are takling about [Shared Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker). [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) are tied to the page context and die with it. Also, XHR is AJAX, *(when the async param is not set to false)*

Comment: @Kaiido you're right, I mixed them up. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net) or [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) browser add-on, or anything similar, to automatically execute a piece of JavaScript at each load of a page, which then could have a call to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("postmessage")[0].click();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onload event of document body as below

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){
     document.getElementsByClassName("postmessage")[0].click()
});
```

This code will work event you refresh the page.
See document related to event [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)